# Project (AWS CDK) and Lambda specific python imports

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-import, aws-cdk

Image you are writing an IaaC (Infrastructure as a Code) project with python programming language. There is a good library/sdk that makes it convenient: AWS CDK (Amazon web services cloud development kit). In the same project you can specify lambda source code too.

Now imagine you want that python imports in the lambda function source code would work in the lambda environment and in the project. One of the simplest ways to achieve that is to try/except ***ImportError*** like this:

```
try:
    # Lambda-specific import.
    from some.path import PathModule
except ImportError:
    # Project-specific import.
    from iaac.project.source.some.path import PathModule
```

However, this solution seems to be kinda ugly. Any better suggestions how to write imports that would work in the AWS CDK project and in the Lambda environment?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use the same path for both the Lambda environment and the local environment?

If you pack the module together with the lambda source code, then `from iaac.project.source.some.path import PathModule` should work both locally and in Lambda environment.

If you put the module into a [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), then you can install that module locally using `pip`, and `from some.path import PathModule` should work for both.

Comment: Hmm. For maintaining a good project structure it would make sense to have a dedicated "source" directory where the lambda function code would sit.

Comment: Also, regarding layers - you need to put them in chained directories in order to work. E.g. /source/python/your-stuff. This makes importing, again, difficult.